# TableLayoutPanel isn't removing Controls

Tags: vb.net, tablelayoutpanel

The add is working correctly

```
Private Sub AddColumnToTableLayout()
    Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, (100 / m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnCount)))
    For iColumnStyle As Integer = 0 To Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnStyles.Count - 1
        Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnStyles.Item(iColumnStyle).SizeType = SizeType.Percent
        Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnStyles.Item(iColumnStyle).Width = 100 / Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnCount
    Next

    'For iColumns As Integer = 0 To m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnCount - 1
    '    Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, (100 / m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnCount)))
    'Next
    'Insert buttons for each of the new row ends
    For iRowIndex As Integer = 0 To Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.RowCount - 1
        m_btnMy = New MyButton.MyButton
        Me.SetDefaultsOnMyButtonMyButton(m_btnMy, Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnCount, iRowIndex)
        Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.Controls.Add(m_btnMy, Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnCount, iRowIndex)
    Next

End Sub
```

The MyButton.MyButton is declared in the the class for the UserControl as

```
Friend WithEvents m_btnMy As MyButton.MyButton
```

The Remove function however isn't

```
Private Sub RemoveColumnFromTableLayout()
    For iRowIndex As Integer = 0 To Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.RowCount - 1
        Dim Ctrl As MyButton.MyButton = Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.GetControlFromPosition(iRowIndex, Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnCount - 1)
        Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.Controls.Remove(Ctrl)
    Next
    Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnStyles.RemoveAt(Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnCount - 1)
    For iColumnIndex As Integer = 0 To Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnStyles.Count - 1
        Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnStyles.Item(iColumnIndex).Width = 100 / Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnCount
    Next
End Sub
```

In stepping through RemoveColumnFromTableLayout() I noticed that GetControlFromPosition is returning "Nothing".  I started with a 2x2 matrix and after adding a column I correctly have a 2x3 matrix with button. After a remove I incorrect have a 3x2 matrix of the same button set.  I tried using a dispose on the control before I realized that the GetControl was returning "Nothing".

[image: User Control output]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well here's the rub GetControlFromPosition is not working as we might think. Add another function that steps through all cells looking at each of the cells. See solution

Comment: If you want to remove all the controls you can use `Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.Controls.Clear()`; or if you want to be more selective (choosing certain controls to remove), you might iterate through all the contained controls (`Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.Controls).

Comment: No Just the last column or row.  The anything but Idle_Mind caught my mistakes. And I was heading for what I thought was a well deserved rage. :)

Comment: OK. I don't have too much experience with TableLayoutPanel, but I found pretty curious that you didn't get any answer and that's I commented something. Happy that you have got some help; +1 for Idle_Mind for the spot-on solution and writing a so clear and detailed answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some general notes:

- You have to explicitly increment/decrement the ColumnCount()
  property.
- The ColumnStyle() Width property does NOT need to be an actual
  computed percentage.  Simply make all the columns have the **same**
  value.  I've used whatever value is in the first column.  With that
  in mind, you don't have to change any of the Widths when a column is
  removed, since they are all the same value already.
- You had an "off by one" error in the Column value for the Add()
  routine.
- In the Remove() routine, your row/col parameters were **Reversed** in
  the `GetControlFromPosition()` call.

Here's the revised code:

```
Private Sub AddColumnToTableLayout()
    Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnCount = Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnCount + 1
    Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnStyles(0).Width))

    'Insert buttons for each of the new row ends
    For iRowIndex As Integer = 0 To Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.RowCount - 1
        m_btnMy = New MyButton.MyButton
        Me.SetDefaultsOnMyButtonMyButton(m_btnMy, Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnCount - 1, iRowIndex)
        Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.Controls.Add(m_btnMy, Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnCount - 1, iRowIndex)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub RemoveColumnFromTableLayout()
    For iRowIndex As Integer = 0 To Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.RowCount - 1
        Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.GetControlFromPosition(Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnCount - 1, iRowIndex).Dispose()
    Next
    Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnStyles.RemoveAt(Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnCount - 1)
    Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnCount = Me.m_TblLyBtnHost.ColumnCount - 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Yea I caught that LOL. In the immortal words of forest gummp, "stupid is as stupid does. Thanks for taking the time. Also there were some of you points I didn't realize thanks

Comment: LOL Old submarine sailor understands that one ROFL

Comment: Idle Your in CS.  My old stomping grounds

Comment: Cool!...my wife was last stationed here on Peterson AFB.  I'm still living on base while she's off doing a one year remote tour out in Turkey.  I've spent a total of 11 years on and off here in The Springs.

Comment: Say Hi to Pikes Peak for me. LOL.

Comment: Will pop you an email tonight